# Where is or was the place called Apapis?

Tags: 15th-century, names, norman, malta

I've been trying to find out more about the origins of my rare surname Apap (from Gozo in Malta) and have been reading about its origin through military men with the surname De Apapis.

The first recorded of this name that I know was Milite Lancia De Apapis in Gozo born 1450, during Norman rule.

Since the Normans spoke French, De Apapis must have meant "from/of Apapis". What or where would " Apapis" refer to in this scope?

Was it a place in Malta that I am not aware of? None that I can find and Malta from what I know has a sketchy history due to lost documents. Could this link in with the word "papal" meaning "from the Pope"/" from the father" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mario Cassar, *The surnames of the Maltese Islands: an etymological dictionary* (2003):

> APAP
>
> (1) Greek — nickname (?); < Gk. *Apapis*
>   [De Soldanis], < *apapy*, a dandelion-like
>   weed; of uncertain application as a
>   surname. The surname **Avap** (a possible
>   cogante form) prevails in Italy.
>
> (2) Arabic — nickname; tautological
>   form of Ar. *ab* meaning “father”
>   [Mikiel Anton Vassalli: *Lexicon*,
>   1796], in which case the aggregate term
>   term might suggest “grandfather,
>   ancestor” [MG]. The surname **Ap**
>   also prevails in Italy.
>
> Old local forms: **Hapap**. (**De**)
>   **Apapis**
>
> The surname **Apap** features neither
>   in the Militia List of 1419/20
>   nor in the Angara Roster of the
>   1480’s, but figures prominently in
>   the Gozitan Crociata Records of
>   1533 [Wettinger:1980]. Probably, up
>   till then it was still confined to
>   Gozo; landowner Aloisio Apap is
>   recorded there in 1502 [De
>   Soldanis]. The **Apap** family erected
>   (or acquired) the beneficies of Ta
>   Caddiesa (1502), Habel Don Lorenzo
>   (1509), and Ta Ghammar (1576) [Montalto].
>   (1509), and Ta Ghammar (1576)
>   [Montalto]. The Apaps were one of
>   the prominent landed gentries of
>   Gozo who survived the Moorish
>   onslaught of 1551 [MG]. Don
>   Lorenzo De Apapis (1501-1586),
>   parish priest of St George's in Rabbato,
>   was actually taken into captivity, only
>   to be redeemed soon after the event
>   [Mifsud-Bonnici]; another priest,
>   Antonius Hapap, is recorded in Gozo in
>   1510 [Wettinger: 2002], In 1712 Filippo
>   Apap was created Marquis of Ġnien
>   is-Sultan by Grand Master De Rohan
>   [Montalto].
>
> - Several Jews bear the *praenomen*
>     *Aba* meaning “forefather, ancestor”;
>     Gk. *papas* also means “father”, a title
>     of respect used in addressing a parish
>     priest of the Orthodox Church.

---

EDIT: I've given this some thought overnight, and there are still some things from Cassar's entry that need clarification:

- What does the fact that there are two etymologies indicate? Are there two surnames Apap, one from Greek and one from Arabic? Or is there only one such surname, and the author doesn't know whether it comes from Greek or from Arabic?
- What exactly is this plant *apapis*, *apapy*? I've checked some Greek dictionaries and encyclopedias and found nothing. Given the connection between Malta and the Knights, it could be a dialectal Cypriot word.
- How did the "old local form" *De Apapis* form? Was it a Latinisation of Apap or a holdover from the Greek etymon?
- What are these surnames Avap and Ap that allegedly prevail in Italy? I haven't found any evidence of them.

Comment: much appreciated!

Comment: I can't find anything about the plant or the surname Ap either

Comment: Just maybe, the plant could be apium/appio, terms for several kinds of parsley and celery.